# Fourier Transform of exp(-a|x-.5|)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-restriction

So I've been working on the fourier transform of $exp(-a|x-\frac{1}{2}|)$ (with $a>0$) and keep getting:
$\left(e^{-\pi i}\right)\left(\frac{2a}{a^+4\pi^2x^2}\right)$.

  A research partner keeps getting something much more complicated - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to type an $x$ and a $2$. I haven't checked the constants, but $$e^{\pm\pi ix} \frac{A}{B^2 + (Cx)^2}$$ is the right form.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of an integrable function is bounded, so having $x^2$ in the denominator is out of question. I used [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20transform%20of%20exp%28-%7Cx%7C%29) to remind myself that the transform of $\exp(-|x|)$ is the Cauchy distribution:
$$\mathcal F\left(e^{-|x|}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{\omega^2+1}$$
By the scaling property, 
$$\mathcal F\left(e^{-a|x|}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{a}{\omega^2+a^2}$$
And then shift by one half will produce the factor of $e^{-2\pi i \omega (1/2)}$.

I can't promise that my conventions for $\mathcal F$ agree with yours.